# Why did Draco Malfoy support Viktor Krum in the Triwizard Tournament?

Tags: harry-potter, triwizard-tournament

I understand why Draco wouldn't support Harry¹, but I don't understand why he wouldn't throw his support to Cedric, a fellow Hogwarts student, a well-liked guy in general, and also a Seeker, like Viktor, Harry, and Draco himself. I glanced through *Goblet of Fire*, but didn't find anything particularly compelling that would explain why Draco would choose to support Viktor over Cedric, aside from the Durmstrang students sitting at the Slytherin table for the welcoming feast after they first arrive at Hogwarts.

**Is there a specific reason cited for Draco supporting Viktor in the Triwizard Tournament in *Goblet of Fire*?**

<sub>¹Potter stinks?</sub>

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Malfoy **did** support Diggory; the badges he and the Slytherins wore said "Support Cedric Diggory" (as well as "Potter Stinks"). I believe he also referred to Diggory as "the REAL Hogwarts champion".

> When he and Hermione arrived at Snape's dungeon after lunch, they found the Slytherins waiting outside, each and every one of them wearing a large badge on the front of his or her robes. For one wild moment Harry thought they were S.P.E.W. badges - then he saw that they all bore the same message, in luminous red letters that burnt brightly in the dimly lit underground passage:
>
> **Support CEDRIC DIGGORY - The REAL Hogwarts Champion!**
>
> "Like them, Potter?" said Malfoy loudly as Harry approached. "And this isn't all they do - look!"
>
> He pressed his badge into his chest, and the message upon it vanished, to be replaced by another one, which glowed green:
>
> **POTTER STINKS**

(Goblet of Fire, US edition, pg. 297-298)

Comment: I wouldn't put it past Draco to do that with the buttons, definitely not. Hmm ... it's just stuck in my mind that he, Crabbe, and Goyle supported Krum. Can you cite any canon quotes for me? That would really help. I do remember "the real Hogwarts champion", but I recall it as being just a school-wide Hogwarts thing, when Harry was initially picked as a champion. I totally don't remember the "Support Cedric Diggory" on the badges, but I concede it's highly possible. Any canon references you can give me would be great! Thanks :)

Comment: @aSlytherin: I'll find them when I'm home from work. :)

Comment: @Slytherincess - added supporting quotes from GoF (only a year late!).

Comment: There's additional text in that chapter (GoF chapter 18, "The Weighing of the Wands") about Harry having a hard time because the rest of the school is rooting against him (Hufflepuff because they're supporting Diggory, Slytherin because they're very anti-Harry, and Ravenclaw because they think he bewitched the goblet to gain more fame), but it doesn't specifically speak to Malfoy or the Slytherins backing Diggory or Krum.

Comment: +1 I always seem to miss the little things, and thought Malfoy supported Krum because he was almost sent to Durmstrang.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there was a reason in the book series. I believe it was because Draco was a fan of Krums prior to the Triwizard Tournament. He was larger than life and the posterboy for Malfoys favorite sport. Viktor had his respect. Malfoy was caught up in the fervor. Like sports minded muggles, Dark Wizard wannabes have idols.

Comment: Also, Victor's level of success and popularity would have been a draw to Malfoy as popularity = power in the minds of many.  It often at least = influence.

Comment: I agree with this answer. Although Malfoy mainly supported Cedric, Krum was a famous Quidditch star.

Answer (score 0):

Draco supported Cedric not Krum. But any you-know-who, Draco might have thought that Viktor Krum would tear apart Ron, Harry and Hermione.

Comment: I fail to see why this answer had a score of -1 (without a comment) when it's technically correct whereas another answer with presently a score of 4 says there was no reason in the book - which is a contradiction to book itself (it did say that Draco supported Cedric).